# Case statement code does not display on the screen, but complies without error

Tags: java, string, case

I am trying to get the program to print card type on the screen based on the first digit of the card number. The program compiles fine and runs, but it doesn't put the card type statement onto the screen. I'm sure this is just a simple fix but I have spent several hours attempting to discover what it might be. What am I missing here?

```
public static void main (String [] args ) {


    System.out.println ( "Please enter your credit card number without spaces." );
    Scanner keyIn = new Scanner ( System.in );

    long ccNum = keyIn.nextLong ();
    String cNum = ccNum + "";    


    switch ( cNum.charAt ( 0 ) )
      {
        case 4:
            System.out.println ( "The card is a Visa" );
            break;

        case 5:
            System.out.println ( "The card is a MasterCard" );
            break;

        case 6:
            System.out.println ( "The card is a Discover Card" );
            break;

        case 37:
            System.out.println ( "The card is an American Express Card" );
            break;
      }
}
```

Comment: See http://www.asciitable.com/ for what letters 4, 5, 6 and 37 refer to, I doubt that is what you wanted. For future problems: learn to debug, take a look at what `cNum` is and what `cNum.charAt(0)` returns.

Comment: This line is intended to convert the long into a string.                                                                                          
                                                                                                              long ccNum = keyIn.nextLong ();
String cNum = ccNum + "";

Comment: Is there some reason this doesn't work?

Comment: I know, I understand your code. Read my comment again and try to look at the ascii table and the documentation of `charAt`.

Comment: You are comparing char with integer. Change case to '4', '5', '6' & '37'(or some other type). Hope it helps.

Comment: @Egalitarian but what is `'37'` supposed to be?

Comment: @luk2302 : (S)he can only change to some other data type. I just wanted to help by giving the right pointers.

Answer (score 1):

`charAt` returns a `char`, and you're comparing it to the int its face value represents. I.e., instead of `4`, `5` and `6`, you should use `'4'`, `'5'` and `'6'`. Also, note that "37" is two characters, so you can't just evaluate the first character. Instead, you could use [`String.startsWith(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith-java.lang.String-) and a series of if-else conditions:

```
if (cNum.startsWith("4")) {
    System.out.println ( "The card is a Visa" );
} else if (cNum.startsWith("5")) {
    System.out.println ( "The card is a MasterCard" );
} else if (cNum.startsWith("6")) {
    System.out.println ( "The card is a Discover Card" );
} else if (cNum.startsWith("37")) {
    System.out.println ( "The card is an American Express Card" );
}
```

Comment: Yup. That's the thing. Thanks. I knew it had to be something simple like that.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing char with integer.

Take a look at the solution with a switch statement:

```
public static void main (String [] args ) {

    System.out.println("Please enter your credit card number without spaces.");
    final Scanner keyIn = new Scanner(System.in);

    long ccNum = 0L;

    if (keyIn.hasNext()) {
      ccNum = keyIn.nextLong(); 
    }

    final String cNum = "" + ccNum;

    int firstDigits = Integer.parseInt(cNum.substring(0, 2));

    if (firstDigits > 37) {
      firstDigits /= 10;
    }

    switch(firstDigits) {
        case 4: {
          System.out.println("The card is a Visa");
          break;
        }
        case 5: {
          System.out.println("The card is a MasterCard");
          break;
        }
        case 6: {
          System.out.println("The card is a Discover Card");
          break;
        }
        case 37: {
          System.out.println("The card is an American Express Card");
          break;
        }
        default: {
          System.out.println("Incorrect card number");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare card number with your case. You need to convert your `cNum.charAt ( 0 ) )` into `int`. But what about **case 37** ??

```
public static void main (String [] args ) {


    System.out.println ( "Please enter your credit card number without spaces." );
    Scanner keyIn = new Scanner ( System.in );

    long ccNum = keyIn.nextLong ();
    String cNum = ccNum + "";    


    switch ( Character.getNumericValue(cNum.charAt ( 0 )) )
      {
        case 4:
            System.out.println ( "The card is a Visa" );
            break;

        case 5:
            System.out.println ( "The card is a MasterCard" );
            break;

        case 6:
            System.out.println ( "The card is a Discover Card" );
            break;

        case 37:
            System.out.println ( "The card is an American Express Card" );
            break;
      }
}
```

Comment: The way this code is being used, it will work as case 3. I just put it back into the full code, worked magnificently